# pygame.error library not initialized And pygame.error video sistem not initialized when I use pygame.init and pygame.font.init

Tags: python, pygame

I am making simple game about clicking circles to learn pygame. I initialize pygame and pygame.font but it gives me an error randomly when I play the game. When I close the game before I get that error it gives me a diffrent error (pygame.error: video system not initialized)

```
import pygame
import random
import time

#I init here
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

class Target():
    def __init__(self, p, color):
        self.visible = True
        self.pos = p
        self.color = color
        self.startT = time.time()

    def isAlive(self):
        if time.time()-self.startT >= aliveTime:
            global gameOver
            gameOver = True
            return 0
        else:
            if self.visible:
                return 1
        return 0

    def colisionCheck(self, color):
        if color == pygame.Color(self.color):
            self.visible = False
            global alive
            global score
            alive -= 1
            score += 1

    def update(self):
        if self.isAlive():
            global targetSize
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, self.pos, targetSize)

class Circle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, color, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.set_colorkey((1, 2, 3))
        self.image.fill((1, 2, 3))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, pygame.Color(color), (15, 15), 15)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

running = True
gameOver = False
score = 0
frames = 0
targetSize = 20
aliveTime = 10
startAliveNum = 5
screenX = 1000
screenY = screenX*0.6
alive = startAliveNum
targets = []
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenX,    screenY))
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 12)
player = Circle(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), 'dodgerblue', targets)

pygame.display.set_caption('My Pygame game')
pygame.display.flip()

def newTargets(ammount):
    for i in range(ammount):
       pos = random.randint(50, screenX-50), random.randint(50, screenY-50)
       targets.append(Target(pos, (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))))

newTargets(5)

startT = time.time() + 0.000001
targetStartT = startT
while running:
    if gameOver:
        running = False
        pygame.quit()
        
    frames += 1
    text = font.render("{:.2f}fps".format(frames/(time.time()-startT)), True, (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))
##############error here (pygame.error Library not initialized)##############
    text2 = font.render("{:.2f} seconds left".format(targetStartT+10-time.time()), True, (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))
    text3 = font.render("score: " + str(score), True, (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255))
    rect = text.get_rect()
    rect2 = text2.get_rect()
    rect2.center = (rect2.width/2, rect.height*1.5)
    rect3 = text3.get_rect()
    rect3.center = (rect3.width/2, rect.height*1.5*1.5)

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    screen.blit(text, rect)
    screen.blit(text2, rect2)
    screen.blit(text3, rect3)
    player.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    player.update()
    
    if alive == 0:
        startAliveNum += 1
        newTargets(startAliveNum)
        alive += startAliveNum
        aliveTime += 0.5
        targetStartT = time.time() + 0.000001

    for i in range(len(targets)):
        targets[i].update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            color = screen.get_at(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            for i in range(len(targets)):
                targets[i].colisionCheck(color)

    pygame.display.flip()
    ########error here when I close the game before It gives me the first error (pygame.error: video system not initialized)########
```

Could someone please help me fix the errors.
(Sory if I spelled someting incorectly)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is calling  [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html) at the beginning of the application loop. When `pygame.quit()` is called, all pygame modules will not be initialized and all subsequent calls to pygame functions will fail. Because the application loop executes the statement once to the end of the loop, you get an error. Call `pygame.quit()` after the application loop:

```py
while running:
    if gameOver:
        running = False
        #pygame.quit()                       <--- DELETE

    # your code
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            # pygame.quit()                   <--- DELETE
            running = False                 # <--- INSERT

    # your code
    # [...]

pygame.quit()                               # <--- INSERT
```

Comment: @lukz You have to ask a new question, because that's a different problem. Anyway, `gameOver` will be set in `isAlive` after some time. You've implemented exactly that behavior. Remove `gameOver = True` from `isAlive`.